Not able to Notify/read the data from the BLE into my flutter application
I am working in developing an application where a flutter application will interact with the hardware module through BLE protocol. While developing it I was facing problem to fetch the UUID as I was new in that section but n ow after successfully able to fetch it I am fetching the problem to interact with it as it is able to get my instruction but my application is not able to notify the application the value which hardware will provide as response to the write operation.
Below is the code for the BLE_controller where all the functionalities of BLE are written which I am using inside the app.
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class DeviceInfo {
  final String name;
  final String id;

  DeviceInfo(this.name, this.id);

  // Convert DeviceInfo to JSON
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'name': name,
    'id': id,
  };

  // Create DeviceInfo from JSON
  factory DeviceInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DeviceInfo(
    json['name'],
    json['id'],
  );
}

class BleController extends GetxController {
  FlutterBlue ble = FlutterBlue.instance;
  BluetoothDevice? selectedDevice;
  List<BluetoothService> availableServices = [];
  List<BluetoothCharacteristic> availableCharacteristics = [];
  BluetoothCharacteristic? selectedCharacteristic;
  BluetoothCharacteristic? characteristic;
  late String receivedData = "";

  void setSelectedDevice(BluetoothDevice? device) {
    selectedDevice = device;
    update();
  }

  Future<void> connectToSelectedDevice() async {
    if (selectedDevice != null) {
      await connectToDevice(selectedDevice!);
    }
  }

  Future<void> connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device) async {
    try {
      await device.connect();
      discoverServices(device);
      update(); // Notify listeners
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  Future<void> disconnectToSelectedDevice() async {
    if (selectedDevice != null) {
      await disconnectToDevice(selectedDevice!);
    }
  }

  Future<void> disconnectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device) async {
    try {
      await device.disconnect();
      selectedDevice = null; // Reset selected device on disconnection
      availableServices.clear(); // Clear the list of services
      availableCharacteristics.clear(); // Clear the list of characteristics
      selectedCharacteristic = null; // Reset selected characteristic on disconnection
      characteristic = null; // Reset selected characteristic on disconnection
      update(); // Notify listeners
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  void discoverServices(BluetoothDevice device) async {
    List<BluetoothService> services = await device.discoverServices();
    for (BluetoothService service in services) {
      for (BluetoothCharacteristic char in service.characteristics) {
        if (isDesiredCharacteristic(char)) {
          selectedCharacteristic = char;
          break;
        }
      }
      for (BluetoothCharacteristic char in service.characteristics) {
        if (isDesiredWriteCharacteristic(char)) {
          characteristic = char;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  bool isDesiredCharacteristic(BluetoothCharacteristic characteristic) {
    return characteristic.properties.notify;
  }

  bool isDesiredWriteCharacteristic(BluetoothCharacteristic characteristic) {
    return characteristic.properties.write;
  }

  Future<String> subscribeToNotifications(BluetoothDevice device) async {
    discoverServices(device);
    if (selectedCharacteristic != null && selectedCharacteristic!.properties.notify) {
      try {
        await selectedCharacteristic!.setNotifyValue(true);
        selectedCharacteristic!.value.listen((value) {
          receivedData = String.fromCharCodes(value);
        });
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error setting notification value: $e');
      }
    } else {
      print('Characteristic does not support notifications');
    }

    return receivedData;
  }

  void sendMessage(BluetoothDevice device, String data){
    try {
      discoverServices(device);
      if (characteristic != null && characteristic!.properties.write) {
        characteristic!.write(utf8.encode(data + '\r\n'), withoutResponse: true);
      } else {
        print('Characteristic does not support write operations');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error writing to characteristic: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<String> subscribeToNotificationsTable() async {
    if (selectedCharacteristic != null && selectedCharacteristic!.properties.notify) {
      try {
        await selectedCharacteristic!.setNotifyValue(true);
        selectedCharacteristic!.value.listen((value) {
          receivedData = String.fromCharCodes(value);
        });
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error setting notification value: $e');
      }
    } else {
      print('Characteristic does not support notifications');
    }

    return receivedData;
  }

  void sendMessageTable(String data){
    try {
      if (characteristic != null && characteristic!.properties.write) {
        characteristic!.write(utf8.encode(data), withoutResponse: true);
      } else {
        print('Characteristic does not support write operations');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error writing to characteristic: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<void> saveSelectedDeviceToPrefs() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (selectedDevice != null) {
      String deviceJson = jsonEncode(DeviceInfo(selectedDevice!.name, selectedDevice!.id.id).toJson());
      prefs.setString('selectedDevice', deviceJson);
    }
  }

  Future<BluetoothDevice?> loadSelectedDeviceFromPrefs() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String? deviceJson = prefs.getString('selectedDevice');

    if (deviceJson != null) {
      DeviceInfo deviceInfo = DeviceInfo.fromJson(jsonDecode(deviceJson));

      // Fetch the connected devices and find the matching device
      List<BluetoothDevice> connectedDevices = await ble.connectedDevices;
      selectedDevice = connectedDevices.firstWhere(
            (device) => device.name == deviceInfo.name && device.id.id == deviceInfo.id,
      );

      update(); // Notify listeners
      return selectedDevice;
    }

    return null; // Return null if no device is found in preferences
  }

  Future<void> scanDevices() async {
    if (await Permission.bluetoothScan.request().isGranted &&
        await Permission.bluetoothConnect.request().isGranted) {
      ble.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 1000));
    }
  }

  void stopScan() {
    ble.stopScan();
  }

  Stream<List<ScanResult>> get scanResults => ble.scanResults;
}


Here below is the code for the block where it will use to send the message to the machine and it will wait for the response
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import 'ble_controller.dart';

class basicDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  const basicDetails({super.key});

  @override
  State<basicDetails> createState() => _basicDetailsState();
}

class _basicDetailsState extends State<basicDetails> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("BMC Configurator",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
        ),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF0058DB),
        leading: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.jpg'),
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: MyForm(),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class MyForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyFormState createState() => _MyFormState();
}

class _MyFormState extends State<MyForm> {
  final TextEditingController quantityVal = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController recordTimeVal = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController rtcMinVal = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController rtcHrsVal = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController rtcDateVal = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController rtcMonVal = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController rtcYrsVal = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController cipVal = TextEditingController();

  late BleController bleController;
  late Future<DeviceInfo> deviceInfoFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    bleController = BleController();
    deviceInfoFuture = loadDeviceInfo() ;

  }

  Future<DeviceInfo> loadDeviceInfo() async {
    BluetoothDevice? selectedDevice = await bleController.loadSelectedDeviceFromPrefs();
    return DeviceInfo(selectedDevice!);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<DeviceInfo>(
      future: deviceInfoFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
        } else {
          DeviceInfo deviceInfo = snapshot.data!;
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                // Heading
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Basic Details',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                // Input Fields
                buildTextFieldWithButtons('Quantity', quantityVal, '@QUANTY', bleController,deviceInfo.device),
                buildTextFieldWithButtons('Record Saving Time', recordTimeVal, '@RECTIME', bleController,deviceInfo.device),
                buildTextFieldWithButtons('RTC Min', rtcMinVal, '@TIMEMIN', bleController,deviceInfo.device),
                buildTextFieldWithButtons('RTC Hrs', rtcHrsVal, '@TIMEHRS', bleController,deviceInfo.device),
                buildTextFieldWithButtons('RTC Date', rtcDateVal, '@TIMEDOM', bleController,deviceInfo.device),
                buildTextFieldWithButtons('RTC Month', rtcMonVal, '@TIMEMON', bleController,deviceInfo.device),
                buildTextFieldWithButtons('RTC Year', rtcYrsVal, '@TIMEYRS', bleController,deviceInfo.device),
                buildTextFieldWithButtons('CIP', cipVal, '@CIPTGR', bleController,deviceInfo.device),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Widget buildTextFieldWithButtons(String labelText, TextEditingController controller, String data, BleController bleController, BluetoothDevice name) {
    late String dataToSend;
    String value = ' ';
    return GetBuilder<BleController>(
      init: bleController,
      builder: (bleController) {
        return Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: controller,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: labelText),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 8.0),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async{
                dataToSend = data + '?' + '\n\r';
                bleController.sendMessage(name, dataToSend);
                value = await bleController.subscribeToNotifications(name);
                const Duration timeoutDuration = Duration(seconds: 15);
                const Duration delayBetweenRetries = Duration(seconds: 1);
                DateTime startTime = DateTime.now();

                while (DateTime.now().difference(startTime) < timeoutDuration) {
                  value = await bleController.subscribeToNotifications(name);

                  if (!value.isEmpty) {
                    setState(() {
                      controller.text = value;
                      value = ' ';
                    });
                    break; // Exit the loop if a response is received
                  }

                  await Future.delayed(delayBetweenRetries);
                }

                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  // Handle the case where no response is received within the timeout
                  setState(() {
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                      msg: 'Timeout: No response received within 15 seconds.',
                      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                      gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                      timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      textColor: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                    );
                  });
                }

                print('Receive $labelText: ${controller.text}');
              },
              child: Text('Receive'),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 8.0),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async{
                if (!controller.text.isEmpty) {
                  dataToSend = data + ' ' + controller.text + '\n\r';
                  bleController.sendMessage(name, dataToSend);
                  value = await bleController.subscribeToNotifications(name);
                  const Duration timeoutDuration = Duration(seconds: 15);
                  const Duration delayBetweenRetries = Duration(seconds: 1);
                  DateTime startTime = DateTime.now();

                  while (DateTime.now().difference(startTime) < timeoutDuration) {
                    value = await bleController.subscribeToNotifications(name);

                    if (!value.isEmpty) {
                      setState(() {
                        Fluttertoast.showToast(
                          msg: value,
                          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                          gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                          timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          textColor: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                        );
                        controller.text = '';
                        value = ' ';
                      });
                      break; // Exit the loop if a response is received
                    }

                    await Future.delayed(delayBetweenRetries);
                  }

                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    // Handle the case where no response is received within the timeout
                    setState(() {
                      Fluttertoast.showToast(
                        msg: 'Timeout: No response received within 15 seconds.',
                        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        textColor: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      );
                    });
                  }

                  print('Send $labelText: $dataToSend');
                }

                else{
                  Fluttertoast.showToast(
                    msg: 'Enter the value to send msg',
                    toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                    gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                    timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    textColor: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                  );
                }
              },
              child: Text('Send'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class DeviceInfo {
  final BluetoothDevice device;

  DeviceInfo(this.device);
}

I have tried to look it up on github for the solution related to my problem. This communication between my hardware module is easily possible through the FeasyBlue app. I have also tried to understand the functionalities and working of that app but I am not able to achieve it.

I am able to find the error for this just I have to add 1 line of code in this code for my app to listen from the BLE that selectedCharacteristic!.read();
